# Automatically vertically resize JTable by contents

Tags: java, swing

Do you know any way of making a JTable resize itself up to a maximum predefined height and then provide scroll bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found a way. Not the cleanest but it works.

If the size of the JTable is determined by another container (in my case it was a JPanel) the idea is to calculate the panel height based on JTable.getRowCount().

so it was a simple case of setting something like this:

```
  if (table.getRowCount() > 0 && table.getRowCount()<5){
    lineJPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32500, 70+table.getRowCount()*table.getRowHeight()));
  }else{
    lineJPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32500, 200));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] names = {"COL1","COL2","COL3"};
    Object[][] data;
    DefaultTableModel dtm= new DefaultTableModel(data, names);
    JTable table = new JTable(dtm)
    {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) 
        {
            return false;
        }
   };
```

then...

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table); 
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500)); //your table not move more
panel1.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```